How to check if some tensor values are in a set of tensor values
I have a list of tensors and I want to check if any of the values within that list is not in a set containing tensor values, here is what I have tried but I see this code finds all the values are not in unique_values which is wrong!
`data_with_id = Data(x=x_without_id, edge_index=edge_index.t().contiguous(),edge_weight=edge_feats,y=ground_truth_labels) data_with_id.id_column = torch.tensor(id_column, dtype=torch.float)

#I make a sequence which is Data objects within specific time steps.`
for i in range(start_timestep-1, start_timestep+ timestep-1):
                np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
                id_column_tensor = torch.tensor(sequence[i].id_column)
                list_tensor = torch.tensor([float(f"{value:.4f}") if isinstance(value, float) else value for value in id_column_tensor])
                for j in unique_values:
                    if not torch.isin(torch.tensor(j, dtype=list_tensor.dtype), list_tensor):    
                        missing_info.append(j)

Here is the values in unique_values:
unique_values: {tensor(5008.), tensor(7.), tensor(5004.), tensor(0.), tensor(3.1000), tensor(7.), tensor(11.2000), tensor(12.1000), tensor(17.), tensor(5008.), tensor(18.), tensor(1.), tensor(9.2000)}


If I understand your question correctly, you want to check if some element is in a set. To do this you can use the iter() function together with not in. For example:
for t in tensors:
    if t not in iter(unique_values):
        print(t)

Will print any value (e.g. tensor) in the list tensors which are not in the set unique_values.
